# Need to get the name of link clicked to a modal so that I can run a PHP/SQL query in the modal

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, modal-dialog

I'm using twitter bootstrap's modal.

I have a table that maps mac addresses to vendor names. The code looks something like this

```
        <tbody>
              <?php foreach ($rowarr as $k => $v) { ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $k ?></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="divBox">
                      <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><?php echo $v; ?></a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
```

I would like to click on the vendor name (like Cisco, HP) and launch a modal dialog box with more details about the vendor. The details in this modal box would come from a database. I want to use PHP to query the database, but for querying I need to know the name of the link/vendor that was clicked. How can I do so ?

My JS for launching the modal looks like this atm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like all the relevant code.

Comment: what's the rendered html look like?

Comment: @StuartNelson The modal code is just basic like from this page http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals. Other that that it's a webpage similar to bootstrap with a table on it. Also using the JQuery plugin DataTables.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you can do is set the data-vendor in the link by doing:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-vendor="<?= $v ?>" href="#myModal"><?php echo $v; ?></a>
```

Or you could get the vendor by:

> vendor = $("#myModal").html();

Then wire up your click event for the link by doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').click(function(){
        $(this).modal('hide');
        var vendor = $(this).data('vendor');

        //DO SOME AJAX CALL OR REFRESH THE PAGE USING "vendor" 
     });
</script>
```

I also noticed that you are trying to select using by the id $('#myModal'), but there isn't an "id" attribute. You would probably want a class called "myModal" on the "a" tag and then select by using:

```
$('.myModal').click(function(){ ... });
```